# C# FTP app uploads to local directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ftp

I've just written a simple FTP console app to upload files on a local server to a remote FTP site. Everything seems to be working fine until it comes to actually transferring the file. For some reason instead of uploading the file to the specified FTP site it stores the entire file locally with no in the Debug folder with no file type and named the same as the ip of the FTP site. I'm thinking that this has something to do with Visual Studio's debugging. Can anybody give me some guidance on this?

Here is the code I'm using to attempt to upload each file in a string array to the FTP site.

```
private static void Upload(string ftpServer, string userName, string password, string filename)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            client.UploadFile(ftpServer, "STOR", filename);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the value of `ftpServer` and `filename` ?

Comment: they're passed in in a method above, the ftp is passed the ip in a string
'static class Globals
    {
        public static string GetIPAddress
        {
            get { return "206.xxx.xxx.xxx"; }
        }
    }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method instead of that one,it worked for me.

```
 //Directory sands for Remote Server Directory ,it must create if dir not exist
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://serverIP/directory/file");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username","password");

// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

source- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this way instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx